# Dynamic URL in content-field in Petaho Report Designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have bit of a problem here. I have created report in PRD 7.1 which is showing data from database. The last column in DB is path to a image, that is stored on disk (of the machine where Pentaho is running).

So bacisaly, I have Open formula that is: `=IFNA("http://myserver.com/snapshots/" & [path_to_snapshot]; "http://myserver.com/image_icon_2.png")` which is value of content field.

It is working well deployed on the public server, report shows the picture and when someone click on it, it opens the picture.

However, as I have deployed this on a server that has no public address and can be accessed through more VPN IP addresses, there is a problem. I have to specifically write IP address of server into the formula, and while it will show picture in report, it wont show it after clicking on the picture *(unless you are accessing the server from the one specified IP address)*.

Its also not working with either `localhost` nor `127.0.0.1` in the IP address field.

Could please anybody explain me where the problem is and how to make it work?

*I am not very skilled in web things. I do understand that it is not showing picture, because after I click on it, it is looking for it on my machine (in case of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`) but why it is shown on report than?)*

Answer (score 0):

Well my friend, it can be a lot of reasons, even not pentaho related, but, it's a light in the deep end of the tunnel, you are lucky today.

If the problem is the IP address, you need to register it in your DNS (or company's DNS), so, if the IP address changes, the DNS query will return the current IP address and will show the image.

It's not clear the VPN setup you are using, either the pentaho deployment setup, so it's hard to give you a better answer.

Comment: I thought, maybe there is some trick to find out which IP is the user opening and insert it there :)

Comment: Well, actually if you don't wanna deal with IPs, is better to give your babies a name! :D